# How to create a dynamic array of class in C++

Tags: c++

I would like to know how to create a class array dynamically,  I tried doing a

```
class A{
public:
int a;
int b;
}

main(){
A *temp;
temp[somevalue] = new (temp)
}
```

But the issue is I dont want to limit my array to somevalue I want to extend it, I thought of using `std::vector` and `std::lis`t but I get stuck in the implementation

Comment: What did you try for `std::vector`? That's probably what you want.

Comment: You tried std::vector but you got stuck in the implementation? Wut?

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/63358-store-class-objects-in-vector/

Comment: What do you mean you want to extend it? Do you mean you want to create an array, and then later change its size?

Comment: I dont knw how to implement std::vector I need a simple example.

Comment: To Beta: yes tats right

Comment: @super you dont implement vector it already exists for you...

Comment: If you don't know how to implement `std::vector`, I'd suggest learning about `std::vector` would be a good starting point. You can't hope to do much of anything in a language until you learn it first.

Answer (score 5):

Simple example of `std::vector`:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    int A;
    int B;

    MyClass(int a, int b) : A(a), B(b) { }
};

std::vector<MyClass> temp;
temp.push_back(MyClass(1, 2));
temp.push_back(MyClass(3, 4));
// temp vector now contains two items
```